# why do I have to explicitly ask whether a nullable boolean var is true?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
bool? nullableVar;
if(nullableVar)
```

gives me an error but

```
if(nullableVar==true)
```

evaluates fine.

Not sure I follow on why that is given that if the bool wasn't nullable would evaluate fine?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447408/why-do-nullable-bools-not-allow-ifnullable-but-do-allow-ifnullable-true which has a great, detailed answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition expression of an `if` has to be implicitly convertible to `bool`. `Nullable<bool>` is *not* convertible to `bool`, but the second expression *is* already of type `bool`, so it's okay. Looking at the IL, I believe the second expression is really being compiled to:

```
if (nullableVar.GetValueOrDefault())
```

Comment: it's a good question though, why doesn't Nullable<T> have an implicit converter to T? - aside from the "what happens if it's null" I suppose...

Comment: It's convertible to `bool`, but only explicitly.

Comment: @Massif: Implicit conversions shouldn't lose data or throw exceptions. It's hard to see how an implicit conversion from three possible states (true/false/null) to two possible states (true/false) can cope with that.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive coverage on this Jon. I wasn't thinking along the lines of tri-state. Moreso as to why it wasn't regarded as a check if value is true condition.

Comment: @Massif: `T?` is just C# shorthand for `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: @Adam: I believe the "?" in Massif's comment wasn't meant to be part of the code - it's just the end of a question :)

Comment: @Jon: Clearly (and somewhat unfortunately) my brain prioritizes C# syntax over basic english syntax.

Comment: I shall be more careful with my punctuation in future... :)

Answer (score 4):

Writing `if (nullableVar)` will try to implicitly convert the `bool?` into a `bool`.  (Beause `if`s require `bool`s)

Since there is no implicit conversion from `T?` to `T`, you can't do that.

Note that you can also write

```
if (nullableVar ?? false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response on this. Was not aware of the inability to convert. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`Nullable<T>` is only *explicitly* convertible to `T`. In your case, your `bool?` is only explicitly convertible to `bool`. What you're trying to do here is an *implicit* conversion (an explicit conversion requires a cast to the desired type, whereas implicit does not).

Your comparison is an expression that results in a `bool`, which is why it's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

An if clause needs to be of a boolean type. Null is not a boolean type. By making the comparison, you are creating an expression with a result that is boolean.

Answer (score 0):

a nullable bool can have 3 different values: true, false or null

```
bool? myNullableBool;
if (myNullableBool == false)
...
```

a non nullable bool can have only 2 values: true or false

```
bool myBool;
if (myBool)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `==` uses an `Equals` overload call, whereas `if()` expects the expression to be a `bool` (or as Jon Skeet says implicitly convertible to `bool`).

Answer (score 0):

A `bool?` (such as `nullableVar`) can have three different values: **true**, **false**, or **null**.

`if(nullableVar)` is ambiguous when `nullableVar` is **null**.

`if(nullableVar==true)` is clearly **false** when `nullableVar` is **null**.