# What are all the possible schema class names for a System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry?

Tags: .net, active-directory, directoryservices

When using [`System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.SchemaClassName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.schemaclassname(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.SchemaEntry.Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.schemaentry(v=vs.110).aspx), how do I know what the possible values are for a specific target directory?  I know of `container`, and I'm sure there is `group` and `user`, but there must be a way of knowing the universe of possible names.

Comment: AD is [Extensible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676900(v=vs.85).aspx) by practically anyone. You might gather the *common* names from an unextended AD setup but you'll not be able to construct as *exhaustive* list of possible names.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever -- surely there's some way of querying the schema names from a given directory, isn't there?

Comment: Ah, I thought you were looking for "here's a list of all of the possible names that your code can ever encounter" rather than "in the directory that you're currently querying, these are the current possible names". That second may be doable.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question slightly to clarify.