# How to null coalesce for Boolean condition?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I'm trying to safely check if an `IList<>` is not empty.

```
var Foo = Bar.GimmeIListT(); // Returns an IList<SomeObject>
if (Foo?.Any())
    // Do cool stuff with items in Foo
```

But there is an error with the condition:

> Cannot implicitly convert 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So it seems the condition evaluates to a nullable bool, so I try

```
if (Foo?.Any().Value())
```

But this is no good either:

> 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension .... blah blah blah

So in the first instance it complains that it is a nullable bool but in the second it complains that it isn't.

As another avenue I try:

```
if (Foo?.Any() == true)
```

This works - but it shouldn't because this uses an implicit conversion which the first message said it didn't want!

What is going on? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: if (Foo?.Count > 0) { }

Comment: @AndzejMaciusovic: that's a bad way. If `Foo` is actually a query that takes hours to execute completely you will miss the `Any` badly. If you want to know if there is at least one, don't count all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter In my example I'm using .Count not Count() .Count is already calculated field on IList, in fact it is a bit faster to use .Count instead of .Any(). on List.

Comment: @AndzejMaciusovic: true, but people will understand this as a good way in general and overlook the missing paranthesis(In VB.NET they're optional anyway).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can  compare with the `bool?` if you use `==`, that's indeed the best/simplest approach:

```
if (Foo?.Any() == true) ...
```

as to the why it's not allowed in an `if` but with `==`, [Jon Skeet can explain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/447429/284240) it much better:

> There's no implicit conversion from `Nullable<bool>` to `bool`. There is
> an implicit conversion from `bool` to `Nullable<bool>` and that's what
> happens (in language terms) to each of the bool constants in the first
> version. The bool operator==(`Nullable<bool>`, `Nullable<bool>`) operator
> is then applied. (This isn't quite the same as other lifted operators - the result is just `bool`, not `Nullable<bool>`).
>
> In other words, the expression `fred == false` is of type `bool`,
> whereas the expression `fred` is of type `Nullable<bool>` hence you
> can't use it as the "if" expression.

So the `if` allows only `bool` and you have a `bool?`, but the `==` operator converts the `bool` to a `bool?` and you can compare two `bool?`.

Comment: OP already tried this _This works - but it shouldn't because this uses an implicit conversion which the first message said it didn't want!_

Comment: @Pikoh: fixed :)

Comment: Using the @JonSkeet card huh? :) Right,now it does explain it, +1

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**:

It seems like the cause of the `bool?` is the `Foo?.Any()` itself. If you do not want to compare it with `true`, I would suggest you to have temporary variable:

```
bool? any = Foo?.Any(); 
if (any.Value) ...
```

Alternatively, if the object is a class, you could use `FirstOrDefault() != null` as checking condition. It won't take time because it will only get the first object:

```
if (Foot?.FirstOrDefault() != null)...
```

I will go with the temporary variable or the `Foo?.Any() == true` option though.

**Original**:

Note: It is to my surprise too that `if (a?.Any())` cannot be followed by `.Value()` or `.Value`(!).

I think what you need is `Value` (property) without `()` (method):

```
if (Foo?.Any()?.Value) ...
```

`bool?` has `.Value` (property) which is a `bool`.

Answer (score 3):

`Any()` returns `bool` but `Foo?.Any()` will return `bool?`

So `Foo?.Any().Value` won't compile since `Any()` returns a `bool` that doesn't have a member `Value`.

If `Foo` is `null`, `Any()` won't be executed because the statement will return `null` without interpreting the part behind the `?.` operator.

But if you put `Foo?.Any()` in paranthesis, you are able to work with the result of type `bool?` and check it via `Value` or `GetValueOrDefault()`:

```
(Foo?.Any()).GetValueOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 2):

more syntactic sugar, the null-coalescing operator. C# 8.0 or later

```
if (Foo?.Any() ?? false) { }
```